# Managing efficiently pages of data in memory

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an appropriate structure to handle the following problem:

- An application is receiving (e.g. from a web server) pages Pi of data of variable sizes, for example a page P1 can contain 20 elements, P2 3, P3 20, P4 20, etc...
- Each page contain elements Tj with a globally unique decreasing Id j, for example P2=[T150, T149, T120]. In this example, P1 Tj element Ids will be strictly lower than 120 and P3 elements strictly greater than 150.
- This means that the i in Pi does not represent the network receiving order but rather the final page order, which is unknown when we receive the page and which can change when new pages are inserted.

These pages can be received in any order. An example for a set of page P1..P10:

1. First P3 then P2 then P1
2. Then P6 then P5 then P4
3. Then P10 then P9
4. Then P8 then P7 (note that P10 and P9 would be the 8th and 9th page before insertion of these pages).

I want to find a structure that allows me to do the following:

- Inserting new pages anywhere in the middle, end or beginning of the sequence of pages (for example inserting P8 and P7 between P9 and P6), thus according to the inner Tj elements. But I'm looking for a better complexity than O(n).
- Deleting pages would be nice too.
- The interesting part is querying: I want to be able to query according to an interval: for example from the 15th element to the 25th. In the example presented first, I would retrieve the 5 last elements of P1 + the 3 of P2 + the two first of P3. Of course, here too, I'm expecting a complexity better than O(n)...

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is storing in memory pages of tweets efficiently as I receiving them ([Twitter timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines)). I could use of course an Array or Linked list but that would mean O(n) insertion and query time... And of course I need to be able to query items according to their "position" in the list in order to display them in a ListView.

I thought about a few solutions but none of them are appropriate:

- First, Interval trees but they allow insertion and queries on the "same range" of elements, i.e. insertion on the "j" but query on the "j" but not the "i". Not sure I can append a kind of prefix sum to it based on the "i".
- What I though about is using a Fenwick tree to store cumulative sums of pages number of items, the i in Pi being the "position" in the tree which would represent the key to which a value Tj is associated. But Fenwwick trees are not appropriate to insert new elements... I was wondering if it would be possible to implement a Fenwick tree with a Red-Black tree but I'm not sure about it...
- Another solution maybe would be to get rid of pages and insert directly elements in a kind of B-tree I guess. But I'm a bit concerned with the speed if I want to insert a page with many elements at once.

I hope my problem is clearly stated. Any idea about a possible efficient solution that scales well?

**Edit:** I want to query pages not on the internal item Ids (e.g. T140, T150 or anything else) but rather on the Element (i.e. Tweet) index. For example in my first example, T120 will be the 21st item (as there is a page P1 of 20 elements). So I want to be able to query an interval [20-29] which should return the elements [T120, ...]. I don't want to search for 120 directly.

Comment: You have to directly access the tables? If not, what's the problem with putting the pages into a table and indexing them with pointers?
Inserting, deleting is O(1), interval is O(length).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I'd like to be able to search for a specific interval in a better way than O(length) because as the list of pages grows, the data structure will become linearly slower if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a threaded balanced binary search tree. However in search, instead of checking a number `x` against a single number in node `n`, you would be checking a page `px` against a page `pn`. Since your pages are none-overlapping, this is quite simple. Take an id in `px` of your choice (`x`) and check it against the minimum and maximum of `pn` (`pn_min`, `pn_max`).  Then:

```
if pn_min <= x <= pn_max
    the page you are looking for
if x < pn_min
    go left
if x > pn_max
    go right
```

To be able to retrieve ids in a range, you'd first find the minimum of that range in the tree (`x`) (using a normal search). If it didn't exist, it means that you had searched down to a leaf. Call that `pn`:

```
if x < pn_min
    start from pn
if x > pn_max
    start from pn->next
```

where `pn->next` is the next node in the threaded tree. Now you have a starting page. Simply go through the page and retrieve ids until you reach the maximum of the range. If the page ends, go to the `next` page in the threaded tree and continue as above.

Since the tree is balanced, this should give you `O(logn)` in search/insert/delete operations and since it's threaded, it should give you `O(logn + k)` (where `k` is the number of ids in a given range) in interval queries.

---

Note: your tree doesn't need to have threads in both directions. [GNU's libavl](http://adtinfo.org/libavl.html/index.html) seems to have the tools you need, but if it's simpler, or if you have to write it yourself, you could consider a right-threaded tree only.

---

**Edit**: Querying for a range based on the `r`th to `s`th id.

With a slight modification, you can achieve this also. The algorithm is the same as finding a range of actual ids, except finding the first element is different.

Let's append a number to each node that says how many ids are inserted to the left of this node. Call this `pn_before`. Also, call `pn_size` as the number of ids in `pn`. Now searching for the `rth` id (which is the first in range of `[rth, sth]` ids) becomes as follows:

```
passed = 0
pn = root
while pn not leaf
    if passed + pn_before < rth <= passed + pn_before + pn_size
        the node you are looking for
    if rth <= passed + pn_before
        go left
    if rth > passed + pn_before + pn_size
        passed += pn_before + pn_size
        go right
```

To explain what is `passed`, imagine the following tree

```
          __________ p3 {5, 6} before: 4___________
         /                                         \
  ______p2 {2, 3, 4} before: 1              _______p5 {9}: before 2_____
 /                                         /                            \
p1 {1} before: 0                          p4 {7, 8}: before 0           p6 ...
```

Now let's say you are looking for the 7th element (which also has id 7 in this example). If you look at the root (`p3`), you will see that there are 4 ids before it, 2 ids inside it. Therefore, the 3rd if applies and you go right. Now in this new tree, you know that you have already passed 4+2 ids, so instead of looking for 7th element, you have to look for 1st element.  The variable `passed` helps keep track of what ids are jumped over when you go right.

Alternatively, you could have reduced `pn_before` and `pn_size` from `rth`, so `rth` actually becomes smaller every time. It's the same (but remember to back up `rth` because you'd need it later)

Once you found the position of the `rth` element, you continue as the previous interval query algorithm.

Only remaining problem now is updating `pn_before`. Well this is quite simple. Since each root of each subtree keeps track of only it's left sub-tree, then on insert/delete, you would need to go upwards to the root of the tree and add/remove `pn_before` of that node by the amount of ids just inserted/deleted. Remember to only change parents where you go up from the left child. If you go up to a parent and you are on the right child, the parent doesn't need to keep track of you. Note that in that case you shouldn't stop because the parent may be the left child of its own parent.

Do it on paper and you'll get it ;)

Another note: pay attention to `pn_before` when you rebalance the tree.

The search is again `O(logn + k)` where `k` is the number of ids in the interval you are querying (`s - r`). The additional step backwards to the root in insert/delete doesn't change the order of those algorithms since the step backwards is also `O(logn)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing me to threaded tree. That's interesting to get "following pages" easily once you find the right "starting page" indeed.
But the problem is that I want to query pages not on the internal item Ids (e.g. T140, T150 or anything else) but rather on the Item index in the list. For example in my first example, T120 will be the 21st item (as there is a page P1 of 20 elements). So I want to be able to query an interval [20-29] which should return the elements [T120, ...]. I don't want to search for 120 directly. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @Ratamovic, I added a solution for that

Comment: Thank you for this quite complete answer. Your pn_before is a prefix sum such as the ones used in the Fenwick tree as far as I understand, which seems good to me. The only thing I'm not seeing clearly is about insert/delete: with a standard binary search tree, this is easy like you explained (you append the node, update parents prefix sum if on the left branch). This is fine. But, what about a balanced tree (e.g. a Red Black tree or anything else) on which we apply rotations and everything when inserting? Can we easily maintain these properties?

Comment: @Ratamovic, why not! You are rearranging a couple of nodes, so the prefix some of one becomes the prefix_some of the other with slight modifications (for example adjusted by `pn_size`) or perhaps adjusted also by the prefix some of their children. Depending on the balanced tree you use, you need to work out how to fix the prefix sums with each rebalance. In the end, if it was impossible to do it with just the prefix sum, you can also keep a postfix sum.

Comment: Thx a lot for all these precious info! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Ratamovic, I have no idea why I wrote `some` instead of `sum` so many times in the last comment! I hope you had understood it.